# Obtaining a website's web server

Tags: java, android, web, http-post

I have taken up an assignment for a website and I am creating an android app for them. I am new to android programming and also new to web programming (using xml, http post and get, etc.).

My doubt is a basic one. I am trying to create the login page for this website and I don't know if the url of the website is sufficient or I need some other data such as the website's server address. And if I do need the web server address, is there a way to obtain this from my browser? Or do I ask the people who made the website itself for this?

P.S. I apologize if this is a very basic doubt. Bear with me. I am a beginner.

Comment: If you are new, should you have taken up the assignment?

Comment: He probably shouldn't have, but I'm sure all of us have taken/do take on projects we aren't exactly qualified for.

Comment: I have time and I want to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an android application expert but I think you would need to get details about the following :

1. How to pass authentication details to server, for example if you need to get a SAML token from any of the ID servers? Or is it just sending out the plain username and password.
   Just the website url may not be enough.

Please have a look at the weblink for authenticating against openID or SAML technologies
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the website is structured. Is there some kind of API for the website? If so use that. Otherwise you'll have to post the data to the same page the data gets POSTed to through a browser and find some way to catch an error or success. This method is not preferred. Also there may be some kind of central authentication server (Such as LDAP or AD) If so you would have to interface directly with that.

Comment: This page which the data gets posted to, is this the url of the website itself? Or is it different? If so, is it possible for me to obtain it using a tool like firebug?

Comment: You're going to have to crawl through the HTML and find that out yourself. I have literally done all I can do for you.